# How do I get MSBuild Task to generate XML Documents when building a solution?

Tags: xml, documentation, msbuild, solution

I have a solution with lots of projects. Each project is configured to generate the XML documentation file when building in Debug-Mode (which is default). That works when I build in Visual Studio 2008. 
In my build script on my integration server I advise MSBuild to build the whole solution, but it won't generate the documentation files. What can I do?

I already tried to explicitly give the Debug-Condition to the build process, but it makes no difference.

```
<Target Name="BuilSolution">
     <MSBuild Projects="C:\Path\To\MySolution.sln" targets="Build" Properties="SolutionConfigurationPlatforms='Debug|Any CPU'"/>
</Target>
```

There seem to be some ideas to solve this problem when building single projects, but I can't afford to do this, so I need a hint for doing it this way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this all the time with my CI server.  Just pass properties as follows:

Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=Any CPU"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't work eiter. It won't generate the XML documentation files.

Comment: Seems like your configuration works quite well. I had some errors in my project configuration, that's why it didn't work in the first place. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

In VS 2010, you can either do this in C# project properties, or you can define a `DocumentationFile` property in your .csproj file.  For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <DocumentationFile>$(OutputPath)MyAssembly.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The MSBuild code in `$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets` will condition on that property being defined - if it is, your XML Comments file will be created.

Comment: In addition to the answer of @crimbo, if you don't know the assembly name in advance you can use <DocumentationFile>$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>

Answer (score 4):

Project properties are different for each configuration. In your project properties you have enabled XML document only for the debug config. Switch to the release config and enable it for that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess - the only thing I can see that might help is to set the GenerateDocumentation parameter in your build script.

To quote from a bit of MSDN (that references .NET 4, so I'm not certain that this is applicable): 
GenerateDocumentation 
A boolean parameter that indicates whether documentation is generated by the build. If true, the build generates documentation information and puts it in an .xml file together with the name of the executable file or library that the build task created.